# Bootstrap row class each third element with vue template

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```
<template id="players-template">
<div class="col-md-4" v-for="player in players">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">
                <a href="#">{{ player.username }}</a>
                <span class="small pull-right">{{ player.createdAt }}</span>
            </h3>
        </div>

        <div class="panel-body">
            <img alt="" class="img-circle center-block">
        </div>
        <div class="panel-footer">
            <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified" role="group" aria-label="...">
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-success send-message" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Wyślij wiadomość" id="{{ player.username }}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span>&nbsp;</a>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-info" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Pokaż profil"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>&nbsp;</a>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-primary" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Zobacz szczegółowe informacje o poście"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-option-horizontal"></span>&nbsp;</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I created the template for showing players on my site. I don't know how can I add new `<div class="row">` every third panel.

Comment: I want do this without jQuery. Just using Vue templates. @DrinkinPeople

Comment: You'll need to do some rearranging of your template to figure something out, but you can use the `$index` variable whenever you're inside a `v-for` http://vuejs.org/guide/list.html#v-for .  So if $index is divisible by 3 you'd do something

Comment: @Jeff could you show me how to do that?

Comment: It's the same poster as well.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a simplified example that might help.

This uses a custom filter to "chunk" the players into groups of 3. The outer loop iterates over each chunk and creates the rows and the inner loop iterates over each player and creates the columns.

**Html**

```
<div id="app" class="container">
  <div v-for="row in players | chunk 3" class="row">
    <div v-for="player in row" class="col-sm-4">
      {{ player.name }}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
Vue.filter('chunk', function (value, size) {
  return _.chunk(value, size); // using lodash
})

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        message: 'Players',
        players: [
          { name : "Player 1"},
          { name : "Player 2"},
          { name : "Player 3"},
          { name : "Player 4"},
          { name : "Player 5"},
          { name : "Player 6"},
          { name : "Player 7"},
          { name : "Player 8"}
        ]
    }
})
```

[Full Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/peterburrell/ko8gLkwt/)

Comment: Are you seriously doing this to us? DO NOT USE LODASH!

Comment: @OzanKurt Care to elaborate? What's wrong with lodash?

Comment: @Peter Thanks for this. Set me on the right path, elegant solution!

Comment: @ceejayoz It's just an extra dependency and an extra http request.

Comment: @OzanKurt Vue's really supposed to be used with Webpack/Browserify, which would prevent the HTTP request (and lets you include just individual lodash functions as needed, instead of the entire thing), and I'd say lodash is pretty close to becoming a defacto standard library (which JS finds quite lacking natively) for string/array stuff.

Comment: FYI: latest Vue fails to compile the template in the fiddle.

Comment: Update version for VueJS 2.0 here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41924476/vuejs-v-for-add-bootstrap-row-every-5-items/43439376#43439376

Comment: Very sexy solution.