# vuejs v-for add bootstrap row every 5 items

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, vue.js

I have an array of items like 'Item 1', 'Item 2' up to 'Item 25'. I want the HTML after rendering look like this:

```
<div class="row">
   <div>Item 1</div>
   <div>Item 2</div>
   <div>Item 3</div>
   <div>Item 4</div>
   <div>Item 5</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
   <div>Item 6</div>
   <div>Item 7</div>
   <div>Item 8</div>
   <div>Item 9</div>
   <div>Item 10</div>
</div>
```

What is the proper way to express this in vue.js?

```
 <div class="row">
    <span  v-for="(item, index) in items">
         // do something like this in vue.js style: 
         // if (item % 5 == 0) print "</div><div class='row'>"
         <app-field >{{ item }}</app-field>
    </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Or you can do the same using `lodash _.chunk()`, which personally I find more readable.

Template:

```
<div class="columns" v-for="chunk in productChunks">

    <div class="column is-one-quarter" v-for="product in chunk">
       // stuff
    </div>

</div>
```

Then

```
    computed: {
      productChunks(){
          return _.chunk(Object.values(this.products), 4);
      }
    },
```

Personally I import lodash globally as I use it so often, in main.js:

```
import _ from 'lodash'
```

Remember to '`npm install --save lodash`'

Comment: In my opinion this is much better than the accepted answer, as it keeps every logic away from the template.

Answer (score 66):

You can try this:

```
  <div class="row" v-for="i in Math.ceil(items.length / 5)">
    <span v-for="item in items.slice((i - 1) * 5, i * 5)">
      {{item}}
    </span>
  </div>
```

See a working example:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data: {
    items: [
      'item 1',
      'item 2',
      'item 3',
      'item 4',
      'item 5',
      'item 6',
      'item 7',
      'item 8',
      'item 9',
      'item 10',
      'item 11',
      'item 12',
      'item 13',
      'item 14',
      'item 15',
      'item 16',
      'item 17',
      'item 18',
      'item 19',
      'item 20',
      'item 21',
      'item 22',
      'item 23',
      'item 24',
      'item 25'
    ]
  }
})
```

```css
.row {
  border: solid 1px #404040;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://vuejs.org/js/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <div class="row" v-for="i in Math.ceil(items.length / 5)">
    <span v-for="item in items.slice((i - 1) * 5, i * 5)">
  {{item}}
</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: **up to 'Item 25'** so:
`i in Math.ceil(items.length / 5)`

Comment: See @Cristi Jora answer for a cleaner way

Comment: @CD.. how to retrieve the real index of `item` ? I've a v-model in the v-for based on the index of item. And your solution give me the index : 0,1,0,1,0 ... instead of 0,1,2,3,4 .. (ps: i changed 5 by 2)

Comment: I created a question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51589387/v-for-add-row-every-2-items-give-me-the-wrong-index

Answer (score 30):

In addition to the example above which I think is fine, I would define the calculations as computed properties and methods for more readable code.
See the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z11fe07p/421/):

```
 computed:{
    rowCount() {     
       return Math.ceil(this.items.length / this.itemsPerRow);
    }
 },
```

Comment: This anwser should be integrated to the accepted one !

Comment: Agreed/  Much more elegant solution.

Answer (score 6):

A little improved answer, With `npm install --save lodash`.

```
<template>
<div class="content">
    <div class="row" v-for="chunk in productChunks">
        <product-thumbnail :product="sp" v-for="sp in chunk" class="col-4"></product-thumbnail>
    </div>
</div>
</template>



import lodash from 'lodash';


export default {
    name: "ProductList",
    components: {
        "product-thumbnail": ProductThumbnail
    },
    data() {
        return {
            sps: [],
            itemsPerRow: 4
        }
    },
    async mounted() {
        let resp = await;
        //call api
        this.sps = results;
    },
    computed: {
        productChunks() {
            return lodash.chunk(Object.values(this.sps), this.itemsPerRow);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're simply creating placeholders/slots for content that you'll probably render later using `position: relative`, you can create them like this:

```
<template>
    <div class="col q-gutter-y-xs">
        <div class="row q-gutter-x-xs" v-for="row in rows" :key="row">
          <div class="col slot text-white" v-for="col in columns" :key="col">

          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                rows: 7,
                columns: 7
            }
        }
    }
</script>

<style>
    .slot {
        background: #444;
        border-radius: 8px;
        border: 1px #2e2d28 solid;
    }
</style>
```