# V-for add row every 2 items give me the wrong Index

Tags: javascript, vue.js

For a design a need a "table" style, every 2 `Item` I need a row. It's working great in the front side. However my v-model is based on the index (item_index) of `Item` and my code doesn't give me the expected Index :

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data: {
    items: [
      'item 0',
      'item 1',
      'item 2',
      'item 3',
      'item 4',
      'item 5',
      'item 6',
      'item 7',
      'item 8',
      'item 9',
      'item 10'
    ]
  }
})
```

```css
.row {
  padding: 10px;
}

span {
  background: rgba(255,0,0,.3);
}

span:nth-child(odd) {
  background: rgba(0,255,0,.3);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://vuejs.org/js/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <div class="row" v-for="i in Math.ceil(items.length / 2)">
    <span v-for="(item, item_index) in items.slice((i - 1) * 2, i * 2)">
  {{ item }} &bull; v-model => {{ item_index }}
</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see for my v-model I get 0;1;0;1;0;1 etc.

And I would like 0;1;2;3;4;5 etc.

How can I retrieve the real Index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, you're getting correct index for sliced array, not for original one. When you call `slice` on your source array in `v-for`, `item_index` is calculated  for 2-element-piece of your array and that's why there's only 0,1,0,1, etc.

You have to calculate that index based on indexes from both `v-for` loops. 
That would be `(i-1)*2 + item_index` in this case.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data: {
    items: [
      'item 1',
      'item 2',
      'item 3',
      'item 4',
      'item 5',
      'item 6',
      'item 7',
      'item 8',
      'item 9',
      'item 10'
    ]
  }
})
```

```css
.row {
  padding: 10px;
}

span {
  background: rgba(255,0,0,.3);
}
span:nth-child(odd) {
  background: rgba(0,255,0,.3);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://vuejs.org/js/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <div class="row" v-for="i in Math.ceil(items.length / 2)">
    <span v-for="(item, item_index) in items.slice((i - 1) * 2, i * 2)">
  {{ item }} - v-model = {{ (i-1)*2 + item_index }}
</span>
  </div>
</div>
```