# Vue: Create a column layout using v-for

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have an array of items and I would like to create a layout like below in Vue. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41924476/vuejs-v-for-add-bootstrap-row-every-5-items) question solves the issue partially however, in my case, I need 1 + 3 + 3. Any help is appreciated. Thank you!
[image: column layout]

Relevant code

```
<div v-if="posts.length">
  <post-list
     v-for="post in posts"
     :key="post.id"
     :post="post"
     :size="post.media_414x276"
  />
</div>

  computed: {
    posts() {
      return this.$store.getters.requestedItems(this.request)
    }
  },
  methods: {
    getPosts() {
      return this.$store.dispatch('getItems', this.request)
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.getPosts()
  }
```

Edit:

Probably have a `totalItems` property in data and calculate columns accordingly.

Desired html output

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col s12 m4">
       <div>Item 1</div>       
    </div>
    <div class="col s12 m4">
       <div>Item 2</div>
       <div>Item 3</div>
       <div>Item 4</div>       
    </div>
    <div class="col s12 m4">
       <div>Item 5</div>
       <div>Item 6</div>
       <div>Item 7</div>       
    </div>  
    <div class="col s12 m4"> <!-- repeat if more items  --> 

    </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Do you need to repeat this type of row or just the one?

Comment: Is *'repeat if more items'* a group of 1 or a group of 3?

Comment: A group of three. However, there wont be more than 4 groups of 3s, so 13 items in total max. I want to make it into a slider (probably flickity/owl slider).

Comment: Search for array chunking, there is plenty of solutions out there.